# Django compared to Microservices

Tags: django, system-design

I've been learning what microservices are and heard something like this: when you use microservices, if **one part of your system fails** (say the card processing part of an online store platform), **you can still use others** (like browsing products in the store).

However, I have experience with Django and I know that if you **mess up a function** for card processing, you **CAN still use the rest of the platform**, it will just **fail when you use that function**. So, is Django then automatically microservices? Thanks!

Comment: Say suppose the Django server crashes then all the services will be down, This is not the case in microservice. The individual microservice run independently.

Comment: @PavanKumarTS Ahhh, I see. So it's not about a function "messing up" it's about the server crashing. Do you think Django could work to build a microservice architecture? It seems a little bit wonky. Do you have experience building microservice architectures in Django? If so, I can ask another question and send you the link and accept your answer.

Comment: you could use Django as microservice with DRF, just split all the operations and create separate project and integrate all together.eg:- say you have huge Ecom web site create independent Django projects for Registration, Authorisation ,Payments, Reports, Order Management, Delivery Management. even though its single project the operation is divided into micro apps.